# How to define the Orion payload to show markers on an image

Tags: fiware-orion

I need to show on the background image (800x500 px) a set of markers (like markers on a map) and I want to know how to represent them in JSON format in my Orion context information.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure how these markers look like... Could you provide some example, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you think Orion is the best place to store your markers?

Comment: I have installed a set of sensors (i.e. temperature and humidity) allocated in a building in different rooms. I want to display data in real time on a map (of the building) through my web application. I want to use custom markers with a tooltip (on mouse over) to show the current values (temp and humidity) and the last update timestamp

Comment: I'm trying with this payload: "position":{
            "type":"Array",
            "value":[240, 380]
         }

Comment: What's the meaning of [240, 380]? Coordinates?